# How can I optimize this neo4j query?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

The query is for loading the 1 million ratings from Grouplens dataset. I have already created nodes for users and movies, and now am merging them in relationships with movies.

```
load csv from "file:///ratings.csv" as row fieldterminator ';' 
MERGE (u:User {userID:toInt(row[0])} ) 
MERGE (m:Movie {movieID:toInt(row[1])} ) 
MERGE (u)-[r:RATING {value:toInt(row[3])} ]->(m)
```

This query takes a very long time when allocated 2GB RAM in the JVM (laptop,  4GB RAM), although runs reasonably fast with 4-6 GB RAM (desktop). Also, I have indexes on Users and Movies with their respective IDs.

The profile of this query looks like this-

[image]

The amount of db hits look perverse, and I think I can optimize this query.

(Follow up question):
How could I run that optimized cypher query in neo4j-shell? Is this the correct syntax -

```
start [CYPHER_QUERY] ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`. http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-periodic-commit.html

Also, consider using `CREATE` instead of `MERGE` for the last line to create the relationship, as I'm assuming ratings aren't repeated in your .csv file.